# Artifactory Pro upgrade

Tags: artifactory

I've juste upgraded Artifactory Pro from 5.8.3 to 6.5.2 release. It does not start properly and outputs this error in log files:

```
2018-11-09 10:31:56,360 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.s.a.e.c.V600DecryptAllUsersCustomData:28) - Start decrypting all users custom data
2018-11-09 10:31:56,465 [art-init] [ERROR] (o.a.s.SecurityServiceImpl:2537) - Could not decrypt user props/keys, cause:
org.jfrog.access.client.AccessClientHttpException: HTTP response status 500:Failed on executing /api/v1/users/, with response: {
  "errors" : [ {
    "code" : "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR"
  } ]
}
        at org.jfrog.access.client.http.AccessHttpClient.createRestResponse(AccessHttpClient.java:161)
        at org.jfrog.access.client.http.AccessHttpClient.restCall(AccessHttpClient.java:112)
        at org.jfrog.access.client.AccessClientBaseImpl.findAll(AccessClientBaseImpl.java:77)
        at org.jfrog.access.client.AccessClientBaseImpl.findAll(AccessClientBaseImpl.java:68)
        at org.jfrog.access.client.user.UsersClientImpl.findUsers(UsersClientImpl.java:49)
        at org.artifactory.security.SecurityServiceImpl.decryptAllUserProps(SecurityServiceImpl.java:2512)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:201)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy146.decryptAllUserProps(Unknown Source)
        at org.artifactory.security.access.emigrate.conveter.V600DecryptAllUsersCustomData.convert(V600DecryptAllUsersCustomData.java:29)
        at org.artifactory.environment.converter.local.version.MarkerFileConverter.convertIfExistsAndDeleteMarkerFile(MarkerFileConverter.java:46)
        at org.artifactory.security.SecurityServiceImpl.convert(SecurityServiceImpl.java:312)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:201)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy146.convert(Unknown Source)
        at org.artifactory.converter.ConvertersManagerImpl.serviceConvert(ConvertersManagerImpl.java:167)
        at org.artifactory.spring.ArtifactoryApplicationContext.refresh(ArtifactoryApplicationContext.java:249)
        at org.artifactory.spring.ArtifactoryApplicationContext.<init>(ArtifactoryApplicationContext.java:136)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.configure(ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.java:207)
        at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.access$200(ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.java:63)
        at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener$1.run(ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.java:88)
2018-11-09 10:31:56,470 [art-init] [ERROR] (o.a.c.ConvertersManagerImpl:216) - Conversion failed. You should analyze the error and retry launching Artifactory. Error is: Could not decrypt user props/keys, see logs for more details
```

Does someone already had this kind of issue ? Thanks for clues.

Comment: Can you check if there is any additional information at $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/access/logs/access.log ?

From the log attached we can see it failed to decrypt, I believe in the access.log we should see the reason.

Comment: Here is an interesting extract of access.log:`2018-11-12 11:36:26,849 (o.j.a.c.RefreshableScheduledJob:52) - Scheduling heartbeat task to run every 5 seconds
2018-11-12 11:36:35,258 [localhost-startStop-2] [INFO ] (o.j.a.AccessApplication:57) - Started AccessApplication in 22.87 seconds (JVM running for 25.517)
2018-11-12 11:36:43,570 [http-nio-8040-exec-8] [ERROR] (o.j.a.s.r.e.m.DefaultExceptionMapper:25) - General exception mapper caught:null
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException: null
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy85.getBoolean(Unknown Source)`

Comment: I've made several tests last friday and this occurs when upgrading from 5.9.7 to 5.10.4. Other upgrades are OK.